# how to set an banner at the bottom of a page?

Tags: android

I want to show the ad banner at the bottom of the page. Actually the list fills the entire screen. How do I show the ad?

Here is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="de.foo.foo.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <Fragment
        android:id="@+id/list_fragment"
        android:name="de.foo.foo.MyListFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Fragment
        android:id="@+id/ad_fragment"
        android:name="de.foo.foo.AdFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: take a look at this answer, it might help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380383/how-to-get-ad-to-show-at-bottom-of-screen-without-overlap

Comment: maybe try this answer also - frame layout can work well in your scenario:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19129992/android-overlay-at-bottom-of-the-screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`.

Or here other way:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="de.foo.foo.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <Fragment
        android:id="@+id/ad_fragment"
        android:name="de.foo.foo.AdFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />// here

    <Fragment
        android:id="@+id/list_fragment"
        android:name="de.foo.foo.MyListFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" // here
        android:layout_height="0dp" /> // here


</LinearLayout>
```

`list_fragment` will fill all space except space that needed for `ad_fragment`